# Upload Chrome extension - default_locale error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, locale

When I try to upload my chrome extension .zip in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard, i receive the error: "The default_locale field is missing in manifest." But there is the default_locale defined.

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "author": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
  "default_locale": "pt",
  "permissions":
  [
    "bookmarks",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action":
  {
      "default_title": "xxxx",
      "default_icon": "/img/icon.png",
      "default_popup": "/html/services.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [internationalization documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n) there's no `pt` locale, use one of the following:

> **pt_BR**  Portuguese (Brazil)
>   **pt_PT**  Portuguese (Portugal)

Answer (score 0):

`default_locale` field is required in extensions that have a `_locales` directory; it must be absent in extensions that have no `_locales` directory.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/default_locale